# Why are the same special characters e with accent showing differently on two of my websites?

Tags: html, css, encoding, utf-8, special-characters

I have a wordpress site (using Salient theme) and a shop site. Both are using the same fonts. On the wordpress site is a text with a e-acute (é) on it. This is showing good but on my shop the same character is showing differently (it seems bolder and smaller in both Chrome and Firefox).

I have tried using different characters sets and html chars (`&eacute; &#x00E9;`). I have tried copying the character from the WP website. I tried converting the character to UTF-8 encoding with Notepad++.
I have checked the css of the two sites and they are exactly the same.
Ofcourse I have checked a lot of other answers on stackoverflow.

I am at a loss.
What could be the problem?

The html page uses utf-8 encoding and so is the database (utf8-general-ci)

HTML

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
```

CSS

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Open Sans';
    src: url('@{fontUri}/OpenSans-Light-webfont.eot');
    src: url('@{fontUri}/OpenSans-Light-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
    url('@{fontUri}/OpenSans-Light-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
    url('@{fontUri}/OpenSans-Light-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
    url('@{fontUri}/OpenSans-Light-webfont.svg#OpenSansLight') format('svg');
    font-weight: 300;
    font-style: normal;
}

.teaser-text {
    line-height: 32px;
    font-size: 24px;
    letter-spacing: -0.5px;
    line-height: 22px;
    font-size: 21px;
    font-family: "Open Sans";
    font-weight: 300;
}
```

Comment: are you including the same font package on both sites?  ie is it the same version of the woff, ttf etc (the one you shown above looks like the light version so maybe you included normal open sans on your other site where it looks a bit bolder). Does the font package on your site include the extra character set? - if not it may show them in a fallback font.  Have you zoomed the browser on one of your sites?

Comment: If you can't produce a [mcve] to demonstrate the problem, can you at least link to the two troubled webpages? Without any more material, we're grasping in the dark here. And [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/MrLister/oddjbrq5/2/) works as expected.